# How do I have my GD::Graph automatically update?

Tags: arrays, perl, web, graph, gd

I have a mixed graph that I would like for my data set to automatically update from a table with work weeks compared to number expected(bars), and two projected examples (lines). How do I have the @data automatically update for the graph so that it doesn't have to be manually entered?

Here's what I've been working with:
(For the sake of making the example easier, the table is the data for the first row with "W25"... and the third row, aka first line, where the last number is 6.4. I'll deal with the others later and leave them hardcoded for now.)

Example of table that is produced on webpage:

```
print "<p>\n";
print "<TABLE BORDER=1>\n";
print "<caption>Projected Weekly Output</caption>\n";
print "<TR><TH>WW<TH>Wafers\n";
foreach $ww (sort keys %ww_proj_hash)
 {
$qty_outs = $ww_proj_hash{$ww};
print "<TR><TD>$ww <TD align=center>$qty_outs\n";
}
print "</TABLE><p>\n";
```

$ww is row 1 and $qty_outs is row 3 producing very similar results to what's hardcoded below.

```
my @data = (
  [ "W25",  "W26",   "W27",  "W28",  "W29",   "W30",   "W31",  "W32",  "W33", "W34", "W35"],
  [     1,         2,     2.8,    3.6,      4,           5,     5.5,      6,    7,  7.5, 8  ],
  [     1,         2,     2.8,    3.6,      4.4,         5.6,     6.4               ],
  [     1,      1.95,     2.7,    3.4,    3.7,         4.7,       5,      5.5        ],
  );


my $graphmixed = GD::Graph::mixed->new (500,350);

$graphmixed->set(
     x_label         => 'X Label',
     y_label         => 'Y label',
     title           => 'Projected Supply vs. Request',

     t_margin        => 5,
     b_margin        => 2,
     l_margin        => 5,
     r_margin        => 5,

     y_min_value     => 0,
     y_max_value     => 8,
     y_tick_number   => 8,
     y_label_skip    => 3,
     cumulate        => 1,

     types           => [qw(bars lines lines)],
     dclrs           => [qw(#4f81bd #98B954 #BE4B57)],
     borderclrs      => [qw(black)],
     fgclr           => black,
     textclr         => black,
     labelclr        => black,
     axislabelclr    => black,

     y_long_ticks      => 1,
     line_width      => 4,
     bar_spacing     => 10,
     transparent     => 0,
) or warn $graphmixed->error;


$tmp_trend_file = 'graphmixed.png';
open(IMG, ">$tmp_trend_file") or die $!;
binmode IMG;
print IMG $graphmixed->plot(\@data)->png();
close IMG;  
print "<p><img src=$tmp_trend_file border=1><p>\n";
```

Comment: It sounds like you probably actually want to use a JavaScript graphing library, such as Highcharts, D3, Plotly, etc.

Comment: What do you mean by "How do I have the @data automatically update for the graph so that it doesn't have to be manually entered?" - do you just mean you want the data array to be filled in with the same values as you are putting in the HTML table instead of hard-coding them?

Answer (score 1):

I don't expect many votes for this, but the easiest way is to add a `meta` element in the head of your HTML like this

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10" />
```

This gets the browser to refresh the page after the number of seconds in the `content` attribute, so your server code will execute and send a new page to the browser

It's discouraged because it's bad UI design to refresh the page unexpectedly when the user may be typing, but it sounds like that's what you intend

If you want to do this "properly", and perhaps update the page only when the data changes, then you need to write some AJAX code which can update the display less disruptively